# Do I need multiple event listeners for multiple audio elements-JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, html5-audio

I'm writing a silly page where I have 5 audio elements named `myAudio1` thru `myAudio5`, and I want to display hello/goodbye messages when each of these audios are played/ended.

My current (certainly not the best) approach is having a JavaScript snippet for each of my audio tags: (this is for the first one)

```
var aud1 = document.getElementById("myAudio1");
aud1.onplay = function() {
console.log("myAudio1 says hello");
};
aud1.onended = function() {
console.log("myAudio1 says goodbye");
};
```

so I have five of these snippets with their own identifiers, all the way to myAudio5. 
Apparently it's a long and cumbersome approach, so I tried to simplify it and came up with this:

```
var audList = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
console.log(audList.length);
for (var i = 0; i < audList.length; i++) {
  audList[i].addEventListener("load", audCheck, false);
}

function audCheck(e) {
    var aud = e.target;
    var audID = e.target.id;
    aud.onplay = function() {
        console.log(audID+" says hello");
    };
    aud.onended = function() {
        console.log(audID+" says goodbye");
    };
}
```

For whatever reason it's not working (Help! http://jsfiddle.net/8176ccnk/); if it did, I would wonder if creating multiple event listeners is a necessity in these kind of scenarios, where the event handler itself sort of acts like an event listener. (I don't think having one event handler that handles all child audio DOM events at the parent DOM level works...)
In general, what's the best way of interacting with DOMs during these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `load` event in the [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) so your handler `audCheck` is not getting called.

You can directly add the start/stop/ended listeners

```
var audList = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
console.log(audList.length); //prints out how many audio elements there are
for (var i = 0; i < audList.length; i++) {
    audList[i].addEventListener("play", onPlay, false);
    audList[i].addEventListener("ended", onEnded, false);
}
function onPlay(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id + " says hello");
};
function onEnded(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id + " says goodbye");
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v15cdpp0/)

Comment: Thanks! Is directly adding the start/stop/ended/etc. listeners on top of DOM methods the common practice in production code? Also, could you have handled all these events with only one parent event listener as per my question?